# Unknown blocking function call in otherwise Async Python3.12 program

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, python-3.12

I have written a very basic async demo to try and understand async structures, however in one of my async functions, I am calling another async function and awaiting it to return a value.

`returnVal = await self.taskFour(self.task_four_var)`

It is my understanding that during the awaited call to the function, the rest of the program should continue to function, however this one line seems to be blocking and preventing any of the other async functions from working during the time it is awaited. The called function uses `asyncio.sleep(10)` which should be a non-blocking delay.

Is anyone able to explain why this is the case, and/or suggest ways around this problem?

Attached is the async task that is being called in main using await asyncio.gather() along with the called function that is being awaited inside the taskThree function.

The other tasks not shown are just printing some text to show they have been called. They follow the same structure as taskThree but without calling any additional functions themselves.

```
    async def taskThree(self):
        current_time = time.time()
        if (current_time - self.start_time_three > self.task_delay_three):
            print(self.c[3] + "Do task three")
            self.start_time_three = current_time
            returnVal = await self.taskFour(self.task_four_var)  ## WHY DOES THIS LINE SEEM BLOCKING?
            print(f"Task 4 has been returned with variable: {returnVal}")
            self.task_four_var = returnVal   
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


    async def taskFour(self, inputVal):
        print(self.c[0]+f"Task 4 has been called with input {inputVal}")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        inputVal += 1
        return inputVal

    async def main(self):
        try:
            while True:
                await asyncio.gather(self.taskOne(),self.taskTwo(),self.taskThree())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("User Ended Program, Exiting")


prog = asyncTest()
asyncio.run(prog.main())
```

Task two is being called every 2 seconds, and there is a 10 second delay during task 4, that should allow task two to be completed at least 4 times in between, but the output from the program shows nothing else is printed during the awaited call to task 4.

```
Do task one
Do task Two
Do task Two
Do task Two
Do task one
Do task three
Task 4 has been called with input 170
Task 4 has been returned with variable: 171
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call an async function using `await`, it will run concurrently to other async tasks, yes, but the code that made the call will *block* at the point of the `await` expression, and only proceed to the next Python statement when the awaited function finishes up. It is *other* concurrent tasks that will run at this point - in this sense, async programming makes the code for a single task to be sequential - unlike, for example, in multi-threading, where the other task would run in parallel to the callee, and one would have to devise a way to retrieve any computed value (typically through a callback, or a consumer worker with a queue)

It is different when you spawn a task with `.create_task`, and pass this task along with others to a call to `.gather` or other co-routine or construct (for example, TaskGroups), which will handle several tasks concurrently.

In the case of your code, just change the `.gather` call with an explicit `TaskFour` call, in addition to the TaskFour call inside TaskThree:

```
await asyncio.gather(self.taskOne(),self.taskTwo(),self.taskThree(), self.TaskFour(42))
```

Comment: Adding task four to the gather like that won't help with the fact OP's task three is dependant on it, though...

Comment: well, of course not, but will help the OP realize how it works.

Comment: I understood that taskThree would be blocked while awaiting taskFour to complete, what I am not understanding is why taskOne and taskTwo never have their print lines executed while taskThree is being blocked. 

I did try what you said, and this just meant that taskFour was run up to the await point over and over again, but the exact same thing happened when taskFour is called by taskThree it blocks all execution during the `await asyncio.sleep(10)` line.

Comment: what is the code for taskOne and taskTwo?

Comment: I just wrote some similar code here, and definetelly, if "taskFour" is to execute some non-blocking thing, (such as "asyncio.sleep") , other tasks _do_ run in parallel. Maybe the workload you have there instead os `asyncio.sleep` is not really async?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague managed to find the solution. I changed the main() function to the following and the program executed as expected.

```
 def main(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.taskOne())
        loop.create_task(self.taskTwo())
        loop.create_task(self.taskThree())
        loop.run_forever()
```

I put the finished example here:
[github:asyncio-demo](https://github.com/ImogenWren/asyncio-demo/blob/main/main.py)
because it may be useful for others trying to work with Asyncio structures, there is a lot of conflicting info around this kind of problem.